# Watch the content of session while debugging

Tags: asp.net, debugging, session

I added a watch expression for `HttpContext.Current.Session`

I can see the Count being equal to 2 but I can't find the actual content. Where do I find the content of the session while debugging?

Comment: Can you not expand the session node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a watch on a specific item eg:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["YourKey1"]
// or
HttpContext.Current.Session["YourKey2"]
```

You can also query the `Count` which is the number of items in the sessions collection:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Count
```

If you want to see all the `Keys` you can do:

```
string someKey = HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys[indexOfKeyYouWant];
```

Comment: Is this still possible? I get a `ReferenceError: HttpContext is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the watch expression for

```
HTTPContext.Current.Items
```

This is object is the key/value pair for all of the session items.